# Javascript Checkboxes always returns true on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I am having a js code which is using HTML checkboxes.

So far everything works great - when I view it on a computer.

As soon as I view the website on a mobile device it does not work any more.

I started debugging and noticed that the value of the checkboxes always come back true on iphone and android.

To make the setup more clear, please take a look:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AA" value="AA" id="AA" checked="true"     onclick='function2()'>
<script>
function function2() {
alert(jQuery('#AA').is(':checked'));
}
</script>
```

The alert message always return true, no matter if the box is checked or not. HOWEVER this only happens on mobile phones, everything works flawlessly on a pc.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Try to read `.prop('checked')` instead of `.is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this behavior, below code works fine for me. Maybe testing with this code will help.

Also, you could try editing checked="checked" to just simply 'checked'.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AA" value="AA" id="AA" checked>
<script>

    $('#AA').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert("Checked");
        } else {
            alert("Not Checked");
        }
    });
</script>
```